# Are HBase rows added in a TableReducerJob available only after the MapReduce job is complete?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I am currently running a long `MapReduce` job which has a `TableReducer` that is writing to a HBase table. I have another stand-alone program scanning from the same table. The `MapReduce` job is 87%+ complete, but I do not see any new rows in the table from my scanning program.

Are the rows added by the `MapReduce` job visible only after the entire `MapReduce` job has completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TableOutputFormat` enables the client-side buffering mechanism by invoking: `table.setAutoFlush(false)`. And the `table.flushCommits()` is invoked by `TableRecordWrter.close()` when the job has completed. The default buffer size is a moderate 2MB, you can change the value of the property `hbase.client.write.buffer`

I think the HBase server doesn't know whether the modifications are committed by a MapReduce job

Answer (score 0):

The ideal thing to do in your case would be to add internal counters in your MR jobs that will display the internal counters on the Job tracker. You might want to update these counters based on the number of "Puts" you are making to HBase.

http://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/

This article might help you better.

Comment: Yeah I already have counters, I was writing to my HBase table from an MR job and trying to read it out from my web-based HBase client at the same time and not seeing anything, so I just wanted to check.

I had another MR job that was loading, that failed halfway through, and I wasn't sure if I would get stray remnants of rows from that failed job, but seems like it's clean.